# How to get the end date of a scheduled job which was scheduled via System.Schedule?

Tags: apex, scheduled-apex

A year back I scheduled "Scheduled Apex" job via System.Schedule method (anon apex).

The job has been running once a day during this time.

Today I would like to check the end date (if any) of this scheduled job.

I could not find this information (end date of this job) from Salesforce UI.

Is there any way by which I can get this information ?

Basically we would need this job to run nonstop (once a day).

Comment: If you  scheduled it via Apex, it doesn't have an end date unless you put one in your cron expression.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want the `EndTime` field on the [`CronTrigger`](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api.meta/api/sforce_api_objects_crontrigger.htm) object. You could see the end date for all scheduled jobs with this query:

```
SELECT EndTime, CronJobDetailId, CronJobDetail.Name
FROM CronTrigger WHERE CronJobDetail.JobType = '7'
```

You could of course hard code or otherwise filter on `CronJobDetailId` to meet your specific needs.